# Bootstrap: using .affix with .navbar-right in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to pin a navigation link in the upper right. This works great in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox (Update: also not in IE). I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it is a bug in FF.

[Here's a bootply](http://www.bootply.com/133435) and the code:

HTML:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="40"><a href="#">Link fixed</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```css
body {height:1500px;}
.navbar-default .navbar-right>li>a {background:#333; color:#fff;}
.navbar-right .affix {position:fixed;}
```

Any ideas on this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is initially the link is static which is `16px(15px padding-right of .container-fluid + 1px border-right of .navbar)` away from the right of the container. When the user scrolls downs and the link becomes `fixed`, the `fixed` position is set with respect to the page. You can try setting the below style and see it helps you, but i don't understand why Chrome and FF is behaving different.

```
.navbar-right .affix {
    position:fixed;
    right:16px;
}
```